# como puedo guardar los meses en un rango de fecha inicio y fecha fin c# sql

Tags: c#, sql

**estoy creando una tabla de contrato**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM sys.tables WHERE NAME = 'Contrato')
  Begin 
      Print 'La tabla Contrato >>Ya Existe<<'
  End
ELSE
  Begin 
      Create Table Contrato
      (
      Id             int identity (1,1) ,
      IdContrato     varchar (50) Primary Key not null,
      FechaInicio    date,
      FechaFin       date,
      TiempoArriendo varchar (50) not null,
      IdInquilino    varchar (50) not null,
      IdCodeudor     varchar (50) not null,
      IdCasa         varchar (50) not null,
      Precio         varchar (50) not null,
      Inquilinos     varchar (50) not null,
      CONSTRAINT FK_Contrato_IdInquilino FOREIGN KEY(IdInquilino) REFERENCES Inquilino (IdInquilino),
      CONSTRAINT FK_Contrato_IdCasa FOREIGN KEY(IdCasa) REFERENCES Casa (IdCasa),  
     )
      Print 'La tabla Contrato Fue Creada'
  End
```

**como puedo hacer una tabla de pago para cobrar en el rango ejemplo enero y finaliza marzo y que en la db me muestre los meses que se deben pagar enero , febrero , marzo**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo regularmente genero una tabla adicional donde almaceno mi desglose, usando una función así.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [GetMonths](@StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
   SELECT DATEADD(mm,number,@StartDate) AS MonthValue
   FROM master.dbo.spt_values
   WHERE TYPE ='P'
      AND number<=DATEDIFF(mm,@StartDate,@EndDate)
);
GO
```

Esta función te genera un registro por cada mes, para ese periodo, como Ejemplo si le pasas

```
SELECT * FROM [GetMonths] ('31/01/2020', '31/03/2020')M
```

Te devolverá lo siguiente.

```
MonthValue
2020-01-31 00:00:00.000
2020-02-29 00:00:00.000
2020-03-31 00:00:00.000
```

Y para generar un desglose en tu tabla por ejemplo seria, la siguiente.

```
SELECT id
    /*Te toma la fecha y te regresa el día primero de ese mes*/
    , DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, M.MonthValue), 0) AS  T_InicioPeriodo
    /*Te toma la fecha y te regresa el día ultimo de ese mes*/
    , DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(M.MonthValue) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(M.MonthValue), -1) as T_FinPeriodo
FROM [Contrato] C
    CROSS APPLY [GetMonths] (C.FechaInicio, C.FechaFin)M
WHERE Id =1
```

Te regresara algo como.

```
id, T_InicioPeriodo,            T_FinPeriodo
1,  2020-01-01 00:00:00.000,    2020-01-31 00:00:00.000
1,  2020-02-01 00:00:00.000,    2020-02-29 00:00:00.000
1,  2020-03-01 00:00:00.000,    2020-03-31 00:00:00.000
```

Ya aquí dependerá de si quieres almacenarlo en una tabla, teniendo tu desglose completo, o si solo lo quieres mostrar